# Problems with changing the image property of a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView that when a function called I want to change to a different ("active") image and when another called change back to the image before. This is the code:

```
- (NavButton *)initWithFrame:(CGRect *)fr andImage:(UIImage *)img andActiveImage:(UIImage *)acImg {
    NavButton *a = [[NavButton alloc] initWithFrame:*fr];
    [a setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UIImageView *aImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.5, 8.5, 28, 28)];
    aImg.tag = 13;
    aImg.image = img;
    self.orginalImage = img;
    self.activeImage = acImg;
    [a addSubview:aImg];
    return a;
}

- (void)setIsActive:(NSNumber *)isActive {
    self.active = isActive;
    if ([isActive isEqualToValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]) {
        [self undoActive];
    } else {
        [self redoActive];
    }
}

- (void)undoActive {
    UIImageView *a = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:13];
    a.image = self.orginalImage;
}

- (void)redoActive {
    UIImageView *a = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:13];
    a.image = self.activeImage;

}
```

When I call `[btn setIsActive:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];` or `[btn setIsActive:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];` both times it removes the image, but when I don't call either the image stays there. So, how do I make it so when I call them it changes the images of the button to the correct image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of repeatedly assigning image to imageview, you can assign two images to the image view: one to "image" property and other to "highlightedImage" property. When you want to switch between the images, set the Boolean property "highlighted" as YES or NO.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier just to do your check as:

```
if (![isActive boolValue]) {
```

Then, do some debugging, add some breakpoints and / or logging. Check what values are actually being received. Are the flags set correctly. Are the images set correctly. Is anything `nil`.

Comment: Now, when i try and NSLog the images, when I log `activeImage` in the `initWithFrame:andImage:andActiveImage:` I get an UIImage instance, but when I try to log the same variable in `redoActive`, it logs `(null)`. how do I fix this?

Comment: How have you defined `orginalImage` and `activeImage`?

Comment: I define them in the first function, and they are properties and I have synthesized them

Comment: You don't define them in the first method, you use them. How have you defined them - are they `strong` ?

Comment: @propterty (strong, monatomic) UIImage